# What is the value of x in Sha-256?

Tags: algorithm, sha256, sha

I am hashing a input into Sha 256
got the value of M15,W15
want to get the W 16
knows the formula of W upon t but in sigma 0,sigma 1 i have a problem

when I am doing the rotation and shift but does knew the value of x in formula

sigma0(x) = rotation of 7 ,rotation of 18 and shift of 3
what is X denote here from my input or from my work?

I want to get the X value but does not knows how I get this because X isn't mentioned in formula. In Formula
he chose the random binary number but i have many numbers

Answer (score 0):

It's just an argument to a function, as those sigma functions are used in a variety of spots in the algorithm.

It's like *x* in *f(x)* as is common in mathematical expressions.

Somewhere else in the algorithm there will be a case of where *sigma0(...)* shows up.